# Правило RULES YII2 для редактирования

Tags: php, yii2, rules

Дело в том что мне нужны уникальные username и phone, если изменять сейчас, то отправляется старый и не сохраняется потому что у меня уже это значение есть и пишет: такой username уже занят. То есть мне нужно сделать так чтобы свой username он не проверял на уникальность

Модель:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * Class UserSettingForm
 * @package app\models
 */
class UserSettingForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['phone', 'trim'],
            ['phone', 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
                $newValue = '+'.preg_replace('~[^0-9]+~','', $value);
                return $newValue;
            }],
            ['phone', 'string', 'max' => 18],
            ['phone', 'unique', 'message' => 'Номер телефона используется'],
            [['username', 'phone'], 'default'],
            [['username', 'password_hash', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['username'], 'unique'],


            [['email'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'логин',
            'password_hash' => 'Пароль',
            'phone' => 'Phone',
        ];
    }

}
```

Контроллер:

```
/**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSetting()
    {

        $model = UserSettingForm::findOne(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['/user/setting']);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно написать свою обработку в анонимной функции в rules.

```
[['username', 'phone'], function ($model, $param) { 
  // здесь ручками проверить то что вам нужно (уникальность)
  // отобразить ошибку если нужно
 $this->addError($param, "Ошибка");
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать save() с параметрами: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#save()-detail

Comment: вы имейте в виду ставить условники ? Ведь на такой сейв может не действовать rules или я что-то не понимаю

Comment: Да. Либо писать сценарии для rules